# JavaScript replace с двумя параметрами

Tags: javascript

Как в JavaScript при помощи `replace` заменить в теге `<a>`  содержимое параметра `data` на переменную `v1`, а содержимое `span`  на  `v2`? Другими словами `%name1` на `'Стиральная машина'`, `%name2` на `'Вятка'`. Создав при том клон html кода записав его в переменную:

```
var v1 = 'Стиральная машина';
var v2 = 'Вятка';
```

html:

```
<h3 class="category">
      <a class="link" href="#" data="%name1">
            <span class="cat-title">%name2</span>
      </a>
</h3>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: а не проще использовать возможности библиотеки jQuery?

Comment: @player0k Нет, нужно на JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var v1 = 'Стиральная машина',
    v2 = 'Вятка',
    wr = document.querySelector('#wrapper');

wr.innerHTML = wr.innerHTML.replace(/%name(\d+)/ig, (f, n) => {
  // f - всё совпадение, например %name1
  // n - номер, например 1
  switch(+n){
    case 1: // %name1
      return v1;
      break;
    case 2: // %name2
      return v2;
      break;
    default:
      return f;
  }
});
```

```html
Before:
<br />
<h3 class="category">
      <a class="link" href="#" data="%name1">
            <span class="cat-title">%name2</span>
      </a>
</h3>
<hr />After:
<br />
<div id='wrapper'>
  <h3 class="category">
      <a class="link" href="#" data="%name1">
            <span class="cat-title">%name2</span>
      </a>
</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Напишите функцию

```
function ReplaceText(v1, v2, str){
    var newStr=str.replace('%name1', v1);
    var newStr=newStr.replace('%name2', v2);
    return newStr;
}
```

И тогда вызывайте функцию

```
var new=ReplaceText('Стиральная машина', 'Вятка', '<h3 class="category"><a class="link" href="#" data="%name1"><span class="cat-title">%name2</span></a></h3>');
```

Comment: не работает функция

Comment: `var new`? серьезно?

Comment: я для примера написал

Comment: `new` - не может использоваться как идентификатор, ибо зарезервированное слово, узнать больше: http://www.ph4.ru/javascript_reserv.php `new` - 7:2 в таблице.