# Как работают функции шаблонизации в EcmaScript 2015?

Tags: javascript, функции, ecmascript-6, шаблонизаторы, параметры

Прочитал статью https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string

В ней написано, как можно реализовать интернационализацию с помощью функции i18n.

```
'use strict';

let messages = {
  "Hello, {0}!": "Привет, {0}!"
};

function i18n(strings, ...values) {
  // По форме строки получим шаблон для поиска в messages
  // На месте каждого из значений будет его номер: {0}, {1}, …
  let pattern = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    pattern += strings[i] + '{' + i + '}';
  }
  pattern += strings[strings.length - 1];
  // Теперь pattern = "Hello, {0}!"

  let translated = messages[pattern]; // "Привет, {0}!"

  // Заменит в "Привет, {0}" цифры вида {num} на values[num]
  return translated.replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, (s, num) => values[num]);
}

// Пример использования
let name = "Вася";

// Перевести строку
alert( i18n`Hello, ${name}!` ); // Привет, Вася!
```

Не понятно, как можно было бы использовать эту функцию. Приведите, пожалуйста, реальный пример работы этой чудо-функции.

Comment: давай по одному вопросу в.......вопросе. Про стрелочную функцию `(s, num) => values[num]` - можно задать новый вопрос или лучше прочитать даже тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/528707/191482

Comment: `где тут красота? Где автоматизация и облегчение работы девелопера?` - попробуй написать эту функцию так, как ты это видишь, а потом сравнить на сколько это будет отличаться и как выглядеть. Возможно ты и правда сделаешь что-то лучше

Comment: Ну, по сути, из всех вопросов к теме SO относится только вопрос про стрелочную функцию, остальное это какая-то лирика ...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, второй вопрос был не про стрелочную функцию, алёша! Вопрос был про аргументы **s** и **num**. И если этот вопрос вынести в другой топик, он потеряет всякий смысл, потому что тут важен контекст.

Comment: Красота - вот она, перед Вами

Comment: `function (s, num) { return values[num]; }` что находится в s и num? Смотрите [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Я тоже не понимаю что тут красивого. Лучше сделать что-то типа - ```let ru = { greeting: ({firstName, lastName}) => `Привет ${firstName} ${lastName}` }```

Comment: @1px_solid_black `второй вопрос был не про стрелочную функцию. Вопрос был про аргументы s и num.` - Стоп! Если ты знаешь что такое стрелочная функция, то ты знаешь что именно она заменяет, а если ты это знаешь, то непонятно, что тебе непонятно.... это аргументы, которые принимает в себя callback функция у метода replace... что это за аргументы - смотри описание метода replace в доках https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @OlmerDale, `ru.greeting(name, surname)` лучше, чем `l\`Hello, ${name} ${surname}\`` ?

Comment: @1px_solid_black, по поводу [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) стоит задать отдельный вопрос, в качестве контекста можно дать сюда ссылку. Вот тут уже есть некоторые комментарии по поводу второго аргумента этого метода - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/559888